# Spring, how do I store java.lang.Class type in mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to store java.lang.Class in MongoDb using ReactiveCrudRepository, but I got this following errors.

```
@Document
data class Letter(
  ...,
  val messageType: Class<*>
)
```

> Can't find a codec for class java.lang.Class.

I tried implementing my custom conversions, but it converts other properties that has type String to java.lang.Class too.

```
    @Bean
    fun customConversions(): MongoCustomConversions {
        val converters = ArrayList<Converter<*, *>>()
        converters.add(object: Converter<String, Class<*>> {
            override fun convert(source: String): Class<*> {
                return Class.forName(source)
            }
        })
        converters.add(object: Converter<Class<*>, String> {
            override fun convert(source: Class<*>): String {
                return source.name
            }
        })
        return MongoCustomConversions(converters)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using *Property Converters*. See example bellow:

```java
class ReversingValueConverter implements PropertyValueConverter<String, String, ValueConversionContext> {

  @Override
  public String read(String value, ValueConversionContext context) {
    return reverse(value);
  }

  @Override
  public String write(String value, ValueConversionContext context) {
    return reverse(value);
  }
}
```

```java
class Person {

  @ValueConverter(ReversingValueConverter.class)
  String ssn;
}
```

See [Spring Data MongoDB Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.property-converters) for more information.